# What's wrong with this?? it's throwing error

Tags: android, android-layout

Here's my code for adding buttons dynamically. While run it throwing error. any idea? :)

```
DatabaseHandler db;
private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    boolean userCounts = db.getUserExistance();
    if(userCounts == false){            
        Button button= new Button(this);
        button.setText("Add password");
        relativeLayout.addView(button);
    }
    else if(userCounts == true){            
        Button button2 = new Button(this);
        button2.setText("Change password");
        relativeLayout.addView(button2);            
    }

}
```

Error Log:

```
09-17 11:44:34.658: D/AndroidRuntime(655): Shutting down VM 09-17 11:44:34.658: W/dalvikvm(655): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
09-17 11:44:34.699: E/AndroidRuntime(655): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
09-17 11:44:34.699: E/AndroidRuntime(655): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.projects.myworldsafe/com.projects.myworldsafe.Settings}: java.lang.NullPointerException 
09-17 11:44:34.699: E/AndroidRuntime(655): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
```

Comment: upload the error log with question :)

Comment: What about posting stacktrace?   Our telepaths are unfortunately on vacation.

Comment: 09-17 11:44:34.658: D/AndroidRuntime(655): Shutting down VM
09-17 11:44:34.658: W/dalvikvm(655): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
09-17 11:44:34.699: E/AndroidRuntime(655): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 11:44:34.699: E/AndroidRuntime(655): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.projects.myworldsafe/com.projects.myworldsafe.Settings}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 11:44:34.699: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)

Comment: @ Konstantin Pribluda :)

Answer (score 3):

You have not initialized `relativeLayout`. If you are setting `relativeLayout` programatically try:

```
relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
```

If it is in your layout file first you need to find it, like:

```
relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
```

Same thing with the `DatabaseHandler db`

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to intialize `db` and `relativeLayout` before your first use.

Comment: problem solved when intialing database class like this :) DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);(DatabaseHandler db;
--old) ???

Answer (score 0):

According to me which i have figured is  you need to give the Layout for the `Relative layout`

```
RelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.relativeID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DatabaseHandler db;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        boolean userCounts = db.getUserExistance();
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout);
        if(userCounts == false){            
            Button button= new Button(this);
            button.setText("Add password");
            relativeLayout.addView(button);
        }
        else if(userCounts == true){            
            Button button2 = new Button(this);
            button2.setText("Change password");
            relativeLayout.addView(button2);            
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you used relative layout in the layout xml or you are creating it through code in your activity.

Comment: If you are adding it programmatically, then use,  _relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);_ in place of _relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout);_ .